# when updating a data the result is that the data is being duplicated

Tags: sqlite, flash, edit

I'm creating a login form and has functions of edit, delete and saving the data. The problem is in the edit or update part, when i'm about to edit for example a username, then i clicked the button edit the edited version is being saved as well as the data that is to be edited. So when i edit a data there is a duplication.

This is my code for the edit part. I'm using flash cs6 and sqlite.

```
   function update(MouseEvent):void
           {
            var stat:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            stat.sqlConnection = connection;
            stat.text = "UPDATE player SET fname=@fname,
            dateplayed=@dateplayed, timein=@timein 
            WHERE fname=" + itemList.selectedItem.data.idd;
            stat.parameters["@fname"] = fname.text;
            stat.parameters["@dateplayed"] = dateplayed.text;
            stat.parameters["@timein"] = timein.text;
            stat.execute(-1, new Responder(selectItems));
            fname.text =  "";
            dateplayed.text =  "";
            timein.text =  "";
         }
```

Hope you could help me, i'm just a newbie in flash. Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont know about SQLite coding but doesn't `stat.text = "UPDATE player... WHERE fname=" + itemList.selectedItem.data.idd;` achieve the same thing as the next lines `stat.parameters["@fname"] = fname.text;` etc etc? Maybe that's why it duplicates or am I wrong and both parts are necessary? And you are sure there is no other (older) function that sends the same info on mouse click too?

Comment: It was just the same. Nothing change.

Comment: @LEE can you add this line of code;`trace("my update funk");`  (after 'timein.text = "";'). You have to receve only one line whit that text.
Also it is good practice to check for errors `stat.execute(-1, new Responder(selectItems, onFail));` and `function onFail(event:SQLError):void
  {
   trace("FAIL " + event.details);
  }`

Comment: @user2836288 I have just read your comment, I've tried it already and have this error Error: Error #3110: Operation cannot be performed while SQLStatement.executing is true.
 at Error$/throwError()
 at flash.data::SQLStatement/checkReady()
 at flash.data::SQLStatement/execute()
 at TRYTRY_fla::MainTimeline/update()[TRYTRY_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:104]

Comment: @LEE i`m confused, you have an error outside of this piece of code. The error means : the statement is still executing. If you remove the last changes - how many times you received "my update funk" message ? You can also check here [SQLStatement](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLStatement.html)